# Parentheses and semicolon after function definition

Tags: javascript

Recently I saw a function in someone else's code which looked like below:

```
function xyz(){ //function code here ;
} ();
```

I dont understand the `();` after the function definition.

Can someone tell me what is the significance of `();` and when should one use it in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 3):

The code you show doesn't compile.

With parenthesis added, this would be a named immediately invoked function :

```
(function xyz(){ //function code here ;
}) ();
```

Most often those functions are anonymous :

```
(function(){
   var a; // a isn't visible outside
   // code using a
})();
```

The code is directly called, as without a function definition, but the point of such a function is to define a scope (which can only be the global scope or a function) so that the scope's variable don't leak in the enclosing one. This pattern is very useful for making your code clean : You don't add any variable in the outer scope and you can't erase an existing one.

Here the function also has a name, which can be used inside for recursion.

```
(function xyz(){
   var a; // a isn't visible outside
   // code using a and calling xyz
})();
```

Comment: I thought `a` wouldn't be visible to the outside world anyway, unless you did like `xyz.a` ?

Comment: @CrayonViolent If you don't define a function but directly have the code at the root level, the variable isn't inside anything.

Comment: It doesn't require outer parentheses if the function is already a function expression e.g. inside a function call `someOtherFn(function xyz(){}(), otherParams)`, also I'd call it Immediately-Invoked instead of self invoking as I associate the latter with recursive functions.

Comment: OK for immediately invoked. Both names are usual though.

Comment: Yes, I see "self executing" quite often but I guess immediately invoked is less confusing in that aspect. +1 for the perfect concise answer.

Comment: [Here's a mode detailed blog post about those patterns](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/).